# Error connecting to database through Docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a mysql service running on port `3308` using docker. However on table plus when I try to access this using “`127.0.0.1`” as the Host and Port “`3308`”, enter the user, password and database name if I test the connection it shows an error:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Also If I run php artisan migrate I get:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = project and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }
```

If I use the port `3306` on tableplus I can connect to the database but still get the issue with the php artisan command. But it's strange because in docker is configured with port 3308.

The .env file is like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: try with DB_HOST=host.docker.internal and check up the credentials :)

host.docker.internal is your machine else instead just use the name db or whatever you named the docker instance

Comment: Thanks! I already have "DB_HOST=host.docker.internal" but get this issues. If I use the port 3306 on tableplus I can connect to the database but still get the issue with the php artisan command. But its strange because in docker is configured with port 3308.

Comment: have in mind that the root account is created for localhost connections (so not for any.. %) if you are trying with different host it may fail.

Comment: Thank you @Svetoslav. That was the definite answer for me. "docker network ls" > note the ID of your DB-network > "docker network inspect ID" > find your database in the "Containers"-JSON-object. There the value in "IPv4Address" is the jackpot. Put it in  DB_HOST in the .env. Now local artisan and the laravel-container itself can find the database. OP should post it as an answer. It would be a huge + for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Are both container, php-fpm and the database-service-container, in the same network? Did you change the database config in .env? The config parameter `DB_HOST` should not show an ip, instead set it to the name of your mysql container/Service. Eg.G `DB_HOST=database`

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to check if are in the same network? Regarding DB_HOST I have "DB_HOST=host.docker.internal". If I use the port 3306 on tableplus I can connect to the database but still get the issue with the php artisan command. But its strange because in docker is configured with port 3308.

Comment: `"DB_HOST=host.docker.internal"` is used for using a database of the host system from the container system. If both of your services (laravel and the database) are running in containers you have to set the service name as the db host. That name is resolved to the ip which is assigned to the container while starting everything up. If you dont define a sepecific network name all containers should automatically be in the same network. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Hm so its strange even with DB_HOST=project-mysql that is the mysql:
    container_name it shows the same issues.

Comment: not container_name, the service name is used inside the docker networks for resolving the container ip
`
# Application
    app:
        container_name: ${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}app`

app in this example